# I implemented Email settings on settings.py, but it doesn't work when I submit the form

Tags: python, django, sendmail

**here is my settings.py**

```py
from .email_info import *
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = EMAIL_HOST
EMAIL_HOST_USER = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
EMAIL_PORT = EMAIL_PORT
EMAIL_USE_TLS = EMAIL_USE_TLS
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

**I define values on email_info.py**

```py
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my id'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my pass'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

**here is my view.py**

```py
def sendemail(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        name = request.POST.get("name", "")
        email = request.POST.get("email","")
        contact = request.POST.get("contact","")
        date = request.POST.get("date_time","")
        address = request.POST.get("address","")
        subject = '시연 신청(' + name + ')'
        message = '이름: ' +name + '\n' + '연락처: ' + contact + '\n' + '시연 날짜: ' + date + '\n' + '주소: ' + address + '\n' + '이메일' + email
        send_mail(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER])
        messages.success(request, 'Thank you')
        return redirect('index')
```

I tested send_mail module at console, and it works, but when I submit the form, it doesn't work.

```py
>>> send_mail('test', 'test', 'iuncehiro@gmail.com', ['iuncehiro@gmail.com']) 
1
```

Where do I need to fix some settings?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: It has no error, but when I submit the form with POST, it can't receive the mail. I tried to fix this bug, I don't know what it is exactly. I tested send_mail on shell, it works but  not works on these codes.

Comment: And `send_mail` is definitely being called? The method is definitely a POST?

Comment: Yes it is. I checked access log and it definitely records POST.

Answer (score 1):

Your email configuration is correct.

With this, you have to make your mail-id less secure.
Step 1:- Go to your mail Google Account
Step 2:- On left pannel click on Security Option
Step 3:- Scroll page find "Less secure app access" option
Step 4:- Turn it to on.

Now start to send mail.

Comment: Thank you for replying! The problem is not there, just my urls.py problem and form action URL  :). I solved the problem now. Anyway, Thanks!